# mysqli_fetch_assoc - Разные блоки

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

На сайте нужно вывести, например блоки с новостями. Но нужно, чтобы были разные блоки.
Например, этот скрипт выведет одинаковые блоки с новостями:

```
$rs = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 10";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $rs);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  echo '<div class="col-md-3">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
}
```

В результате, выйдет примерно такая структура:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #3</div>
    ...
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы через *mysqli_fetch_assoc* можно было вывести примерно следующую структуру:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Title #1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Title #2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Title #3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Title #4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Title #6</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы у каждого блока был разный класс **col-md-**

Comment: А как понять какой индекс у класса выводить? Т.е. почему сначала "2", потом "6", за ним два раза "4", и наконец 2 раза "3"?

Comment: Это не важно. Мне по сути нужно знать, как сделать чтобы выводились РАЗНЫЕ блоки

Comment: `echo '<div class="col-md-' . rand(3, 6) . '">' . $row['title'] . '</div>';`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы не было рандома, а чтобы были определенные индексы у col-md-. Т.е, в этом примере нужно, чтобы были индексы 2,6,4,4,3,3

Comment: Тогда `if elseif elseif else` в зависимости от количеств прохода цикла. И ваш последний комментарий противоречит предыдущему "Это не важно. РАЗНЫЕ блоки" и "чтобы не было рандома.  были определенные индексы". Вы уж определитесь разные или определённые, важно или не важно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что здесь надо понять - mysqli_fetch_assoc() **не имеет ни малейшего отношения к блокам на странице.**

Все операции с базой данных должны быть завершены до того, в браузер будет выведен хотя бы один символ.

Таким образом, задача сводится к тому, чтобы при выводе массива менять стиль в зависимости от порядкового номера выводимого элемента. Для этого в шаблоне надо определить массив со стилями. Индексы в этом массиве будут совпадать с индексами массива с данными. То есть самый первый стиль будет соответствовать первой строке с данными - и так далее.

Таким образом в РНР части у нас остается только две строчки

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 10";
$data = $connect->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

а в HTML части мы определяем массив с порядком блоков а потом выводим массив с данными в цикле

```
<div class="container">
  <?php $blocks=[2,6,4,4,3,3,2,2,6,2] ?>
  <?php foreach ($data as $i => $row): ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-<?= $blocks[$i] ?>"><?= $row['title'] ?></div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</div
```

соответственно, ширина блока берется из массива $blocks и в нем можно будет определять, какой по счету блок будет иметь нужную ширину.